# Change Label Text Periodically Javascript

Tags: javascript, sleep

I try to change a label's text periodically by using the following code:

```
    function sleep(milliSeconds) {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds); 
    }
    function showMap() {
        var str = document.getElementById("lbPoints").firstChild.nodeValue;
        var lbl = document.getElementById("my");
        var strs = str.split("-");
        var millisecondsToWait = 500;

        for (var i = 0; i < strs.length-1; i++) {
            lbl.innerHTML = strs[i];
            sleep(500);
        }     
    }
```

My "str" and "strs" are right. Code works, but as waits for 5 seconds and print the final string in strs to screen and nothing else. What can I do to change it periodically?

Comment: I hope you realize that you're locking up *the entire thread* for half a second! Please don't do that. Use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) instead.

Comment: I had tried interval and couldn't succeed, before I got the answers here, and I found this on the Internet. This was a small project and I didn't care too much. However, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you sleep. In no language is it correct to test repeatedly
 until a date.

Do this instead :

```
function showMap() {
    var str = document.getElementById("lbPoints").firstChild.nodeValue;
    var lbl = document.getElementById("my");
    var strs = str.split("-");
    var millisecondsToWait = 500;
    var i=0;
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (i==strs.length-2) clearInterval(interval); 
        lbl.innerHTML = strs[i++];
    }, millisecondsToWait);   
}
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fkBAd/)**

This uses [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to call repeatedly a function, and [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) at the end of array to stop the function being called.

Comment: And doesn't explain anything either.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan See edited answer. With a fix (`var i=0`) and a link.

Comment: Just needed a working code, not a demonstration. Anyway, you're great! Thanks so much.

Comment: Shame on me? I answered before you. I provided a link to documentation, and a quote from those docs explaining what `setInterval` does. You posted a broken code snippet and nothing else (which I see you've now changed). A chunk of code is not an answer on SO, 44k rep or not.  Sorry.  Since you've since updated your answer, I've removed my downvote...because I'm not doing this out of spite, I'm just looking for good answers (and trying to provide some myself as well).

Answer (score 2):

Just use `setInterval`, that's what it's for.  From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval):

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call to that function.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the docs, which have great examples.

Comment: Sorry, no.  Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, you should now have more than you need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Ismet, if you have further problems implementing it, update your question with the code you've implemented and I'll be happy to assist further.